# csv file upload in Django not saving in database when submit button is clicked

Tags: html, django, django-forms

I want to upload csv file and save the contents in database. But when I click the submit button nothing is happening. Below is my code. Im using Django 1.9 and python 3.4 with postgres.
utils.py

```
from .models import Account
import csv
import codecs
from io import StringIO
from io import TextIOWrapper
def handle_uploaded_file(file, valid_fields_method, record_creation_function):

    file.seek(0)

    data = csv.DictReader(codecs.iterdecode(file, 'utf-8'))
    if not valid_fields_method(data.fieldnames):
        return False, -1

    result, rows_error = record_creation_function(data)

    return result, rows_error


def account_valid_fields(field_names):
    required_fields = ('species', 'x', 'y')
    for field in required_fields:
        if field not in field_names:
            return False
    return False

def create_account_in_db(dict_data):
    list_data = []
    result = False
    rows_error = 0
    for record in dict_data:
        species = record['species']
        x = record['x']
        y = record['y']
        account = models.Account(species=species,\
                                 x=x,\
                                 y=y)
        list_data.append(account)
    if list_data:

                   # bulk_create will create multiple object in a single query
        created_accounts = models.Account.objects.bulk_create(list_data)
        if len(list_data) == len(created_accounts):
            result=True
        else:
            rows_error = len(list_data) - len(created_accounts)
    return result, rows_error
```

models.py

```
class Account(models.Model):
    species=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    x=models.IntegerField()
    y=models.IntegerField()

    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    first_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s %s" % (self.species, self.x,self.y)
```

views.py

```
def add_multiple_accounts(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        csv_upload_form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if csv_upload_form.is_valid():
             file = csv_upload_form.cleaned_data['file']
             csv_result, rows_error = utils.handle_uploaded_file(file, utils.account_valid_fields, utils.create_account_in_db)
             if csv_result:
                 message = 'Successfully imported accounts from the csv file to the database.\n'
                 message += 'The system is creating Active Directory Accounts using those information in the background.\n'
                 message += 'Please wait...'
                 messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, message)
             else:
                 message = 'There are some errors occured. Please try again.'
                 messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, message)
        else:
                 csv_upload_form = UploadFileForm()
    return render_to_response('add_multiple.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^csv',add_multiple_accounts),
```

add_multiple.html

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ csv_upload_form.as_p }}
   <button type="submit" class="action green btn-center" name="action" value="add_csv"><span class="label">Upload</span></button>
   <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Does the page refresh when you submit? If so, then your views function might have problem. Otherwise try to add `action=""` in your form tag in html and see if it works. Also, I'm not sure why you have 2 submit buttons in the form.

Comment: Yes the page is getting refreshed when I submit. Im not able to figure out the problem.

Comment: You need to learn how to debug view code. Use `print` to print out something or better, use `pdb` to step your code through. My best bet for your code is that your `csv_upload_form` is not valid. print `csv_upload_form.errors` in your views and see what does that say.

Comment: Also you need to show us your `UploadFileForm` code, the problem is most likely there.

Comment: from django import forms

class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    file=forms.FileField(label="")------------code for UploadFileForm

Comment: Please always add your existing code in your original post to make it obvious, don't paste it in the comment. Also as I comment before, please check if your form is valid or not and `print csv_uplaod_form.errors`.

Comment: why do you have a button type=submit and an input submit ? Also, you have not specified the `action` url. Which means, it would try to post to the current URL. The other thing i notice is, you are not sending the form in the context for a `GET` request at all. You need to unindent the last else block by one level.